# Is Windows UTC time Daylight-saving independent?

Tags: c++, winapi, time, utc, dst

I get current UTC time to be used internally from a Windows service application using [GetSystemTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724390%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API. But I'm curious, is the time returned by that API Daylight-saving independent?

PS. Let me explain what I mean. Say, I call GetSystemTime and it returns 01:59:00 AM on the day when the Daylight-saving should take effect at 2 AM. I then call this API again in 2 minutes later (after the Daylight-saving change.) Will the second result be 2 minutes apart from the 1st result, or will Daylight-saving change be reflected in it?

Comment: The whole point of UTC is not being affected by local time zones and DST...

Comment: Yes, but does the Windows GetSystemTime API call return the correct UTC time across a DST transition?  Windows (unlike Unix) sets the BIOS clock to local time, not UTC.  Since local time cannot be unambiguously converted to UTC due to missing / repeated hours at the transitions, I don't see how the GetSystemTime call can work.  Does anyone have any insight on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as daylight savings time in UTC.

However, there are occasional leap seconds. The last leap second was added on June 30, 2012 at at 23:59:60 UTC. Time at the end of that day went from 23:59:59 to 23:59:60 before going to 00:00:00 July 31, 2012.

Use something such as Atomic Time if you want a leap-second free time standard.

Comment: Wow, so you're saying that the UTC clock can have the 60th second... Interesting.

Comment: Very rarely. The next leap second probably won't be until 2016 or so. UTC runs at exactly the same rate as TAI, International Atomic Time. (The acronyms TAI and UTC look backwards because the official names are in French.) There' a problem here: We want midnight to be midnight. The problem is that the Earth's rotation rate is slowly slowing down as it transfers angular momentum to the Moon's orbit. One Earth day is now a bit more than 86,400 seconds long. There were 86,400 seconds per day in 1800 or so. Now a day is about 86,400.002 seconds long.

Comment: So I'm wondering now, how is UTC time implemented in Windows OS close to that convention? I should also stop assuming that a legit time check is `bool bTimeValid = tm.seconds >= 0 && ti.seconds <= 59;`

Comment: Microsoft's documentation says that seconds are between 0 and 59. In other words, it doesn't do leap seconds. Suppose your computer is perfectly synced with UTC just before a leap second occurs. (This is a bad assumption. Your computer clock is always off by at least a little bit.) When the leap second does occur, your computer clock and the real value of UTC will now be off by a second. No big deal; hardly anyone notices a one second offset. This one second offset will disappear the next time the computer resyncs its clock using the network time protocol.

Answer (score 2):

UTC is ... [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)

> Daylight saving
>   UTC does not change with a change of seasons, but
>   local time or civil time may change if a time zone jurisdiction
>   observes daylight saving time (summer time). For example, UTC is five
>   hours ahead of (that is, later in the day than) local time on the east
>   coast of the United States during winter, but four hours ahead while
>   daylight saving is observed there.

Your local time is an offset, and daylight savings (which is a local phenomenon) only changes the *offset*.